# How to break loop and then start over

Tags: python

i want to ask how to break python while True loop in some point and then start it over again.

```
while True:
     if a==0:
         print "ok"
     elif a==1:
         break
         #want to start over again
     command = sock.recv(1024)
          if blah blah ==blah:
               .........
```

Comment: So you want to continue the loop. Have you tried `continue`?

Comment: You want to skip the rest of the loop and start over: Use `continue`, not `break`.

Comment: yes, for some reason continue doesnt solve anything

Comment: `continue` should stop the loop and go back to the top, what is happening instead?

Comment: program crashes with exception

Comment: We need more information than you have given us to accurately diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably `continue`

```
while True:
     if a==0:
         print "ok"
     elif a==1:
         continue
         # goes back to top of loop
     else:
          print "ok"
```